# What is the best or most efficient method for removing keys when setting state via React's useState hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

Our project is embracing the new functional React components and making heavy use of the various hooks, including `useState`.

Unlike a React Class's `setState()` method, the setter returned by useState() fully *replaces* the state instead of *merging*.

When the state is a map and I need to remove a key I clone the existing state, delete the key, then set the new state (as shown below)

```javascript
[errors, setErrors] = useState({})
...
const onChange = (id, validate) => {
  const result = validate(val);
  if (!result.valid) {
    setErrors({
      ...errors,
      [fieldId]: result.message
    })
  }
  else {
    const newErrors = {...errors};
    delete newErrors[id];
    setErrors(newErrors);
  }
```

Is there a better alternative (better being more efficient and/or standard)?

Comment: Does this code work? If so, and [it's on topic there](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), this question might be better off on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need more control when setting a state via hooks, look at the [`useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer).

This hook behaves like a reducer in redux - a function that receives the current state, and an action, and transforms the current state according to the action to create a new state.

Example (not tested):

```
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  switch(type) {
    case 'addError':
      return { ...state, ...payload };
    case 'removeError':
      const { [payload.id]: _, ...newState };
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {});
...
const onChange = (id, validate) => {
  const result = validate(val);
  if (!result.valid) {
    dispatch({ type: 'addError', payload: { [id]: result.message }})
  }
  else {
    dispatch({ type: 'removeError', payload: id })
  }
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain the `const { [payload.id]: _, ...newState };` line. It looks like it is an alternative to deleting a key, but it also appears to just be setting the key to an underscore (`_`), which I didn't think had any special meaning.

Comment: It's a way to delete a key with destructuring. I destructure [payload.id] to a variable (which I don't have to use, usually `_` is a good name), and the new state via the rest syntax. It's a very common redux pattern.

Comment: Thank you. That pattern (and the comment) is the answer to my question.